# How to properly bind an event to my button? My button seems to exe the function before click

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm looking at the example codes online, seems like I'm doing exactly like them. But the event seems to load as soon as the ui loads. What am I doing wrong?

From the code below, the click function doesn't load right when ui is loaded. But when I click the button, it throws:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: clicky() takes no arguments (1 given)

class LogIn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk();
        self.root.title("480 - Chat Project Login");
        self.root.geometry("275x125");
        self.username = Label(self.root, text="Username: ");
        self.username.pack(side=LEFT);
        self.username.place(x=40, y=20);
        self.u_entry = Entry(self.root, width=20);
        self.u_entry.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=4, ipadx=4);
        self.u_entry.place(x=110, y=20);
        self.password= Label(self.root, text="Password: ");
        self.password.pack(side=LEFT);
        self.password.place(x=40, y=50);
        self.p_entry = Entry(self.root, width=20);
        self.p_entry.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=4, ipadx=4);
        self.p_entry.place(x=110, y=50);
        self.button = Button(text="Send", width=8);
        self.button.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=4, ipadx=4);
        self.button.place(x=168, y=80);
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>", clicky);
        self.root.mainloop();

def clicky():
    print "hello";

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LogIn();
#    Client();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `self.button = Button(text="Send",width=8,command=clicky)`.

There's a difference between callbacks registered via `command` and callbacks registered via `bind`.  With `command`, the callback doesn't get passed any additional arguments.  With `bind`, the callback gets passed an event object.

---

Also, in case it wasn't clear, note that `command` is specific to `Button` objects whereas `bind` can be applied to any Tkinter widget.

Comment: wow, thanks for clearing that up! for the life of me, i did not see any examples with "command" option. thank you!